# How to make Jquery Cycle cycling on all elements that satisfy a condition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a list of pairs text-images and I want Cycle cycling over it. That's ok if I don't have any other specific needs.

But what if I want all elements of this list to be shown but **not** all elements to be cycled?

I tried the [slideExpr](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/slideExpr.html) option but I guess it's not my case. I can't find any clue, am I missing something or it's not present this option?

EDIT:

What I want to obtain is that all four text-links are shown, but only 2 of them are picked for the cycle, and that only the cycling images are shown.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img class="presentImage" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<img class="" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<img class=""  src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<img class="presentImage" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {  
        var str = '<h2 class="clienti">xxxxx</h2>'+
            '<div id="past_clients" style="padding-top:60px; height:435px;">';
        var titles =
            [   '<div><h3 style="margin-top:0;">yyyyy</h3><a class="client" href="#" style="width:130px; display:block;">&bull; img 1</a></div>',
             '<div><a class="client" href="#">&bull; img2</a></div>',
             '<div><a class="client" href="#">&bull; img3</a></div>',
             '<div><a class="client" href="#">&bull; img4</a></div></div>'
            ];
        $('#slideshow').before(str).cycle({
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  'fast',
            timeout: 2000,
            slideExpr: '.presentImage',
            pager: '#past_clients',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) { return titles[index]; }
        });
    }
);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/linuxatico/MEN7Y/39/) you can find it: 
Thank you

Comment: what are your criteria for cycling? You should be able to use the slideExpr to filter your selection so more detail in the question (better, an example on http://jsfiddle.net) would be beneficial to us

Comment: when I try to filter, I got: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. Why don't you try with jQuery?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your changes, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using slideExpr:

**CSS**

```
img {
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow" class="pics"> 
    <font size="-1"> 
        <img class="test" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
        <img class="test" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    </font> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ slideExpr: '.test' });
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wgN8x/

I've added the css to make the image visible because otherwise the one not cycled would be hidden behind the two that are.

**EDIT: Update**

Just noticed OP has updated the question. I've modified the fiddle to reflect the key points:

1. Only the images in the cycle are shown (CSS)
2. All anchors must be shown (JS)
3. The anchors should link to their index equivalent image. ie. the fourth anchor triggers the fourth image in the markup even if there are only two images in the cycle. I'm not certain this is a requirement but it made sense to me. You can see this in the fiddle.

Here is my update: http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/MEN7Y/43/

Comment: Thank you, your solution works like a charm, I had to finish the work yesterday so I ended up rewriting it via jquery, js with .fadeIn\.fadeOut functions, maybe I'll include your way, anyway I learnt something, thanks.

Comment: brilliant, glad this helped in some way :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery function each.

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Supposing I have a <div id="slideshow"> where I want to put the slideshow, I just give : $('#slideshow').before(str).cycle({....});, how can I integrate the .each() ?